# ERROR: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: xml, google-chrome

UPDATE: Why is it that when I use google chrome I get the error message, while when I use Windows Explorer, it will display everything fine.

I use google chrome to run my web server.
I get the following error:
I am unsure why I am getting this error, i have the files in the correct areas.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

    
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>news-feed</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>publisher.web.NewsFeedServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   
   
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>news-feed</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/news.rss</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   
   
</web-app>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show us your attempted code.

Comment: Great, one last request for anyone attempting to answer this question. Please give a clear summary of what you wish to achieve and possibly add any stacktraces if possible.

Comment: @Juxhin I added the publisher log and I just want to print the items from my servlet program

Answer (score 2):

So anyway, what is "style information" and how look a well formed XML than?

The "style information" is in fact a transformation and XML to HTML transformation examples can be found on SELFHTML...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- test.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="root">
 <html><head></head><body>
 <xsl:for-each select="text">
 <p align="center" style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:48pt; color:red">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </p>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </body></html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now an XML only has to include it...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<!-- test.xml -->
<root>
<text>Hello World</text>
<text>XML to HTML</text>
<text>Transformation</text>
<text>Client-Side</text>
<text>Depends On</text>
<text>Webbrowser</text>
</root>
```

...and placing both files in same place dont produce the "ERROR: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it" message.

Impression
[image]

Comment: This is the answer. Add a stylesheet just like you would add a CSS stylesheet for a regular HTML page

Answer (score 1):

“This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.” itself is not a problem in most cases. It just states response lacks stylesheet, so browser only shows raw XML.

If you are debugging something and encountered this page, the real issue is not related to this warning usually. Check what is written inside XML and google it without the term “This XML file does not appear~” may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not have rss reader implemented. You need to install extension. There are several out there.

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome Browser > click on 3-dots Menu icon > More Tools > Clear Browsing Data. On the next screen, select All Time as the “Time Range”, check Browsing History, Cookies, Cached Images and click on Clear Data button. After clearing browsing cache, try to download the file again on your computer.